# Algorithm to add up values in a circular boundary within a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a one-dimensional array of size `width * height` which contains data from a 2-dimensional array row by row, with the coordinate origin in the lower left corner.

I want to classify the array with `n` radiuses, in whose boundaries I want to add up all the array values.

There exists an array `values[n+1]`. values[0] for example shall contain the sum of all array elements whose indices are located between `(0|0)` and the radius `1`.
The coordninate for radius `1` would be `height/n * 1` on the y axis and `width/n * 1` on the x axis.

I am not sure whether I could express what I needed.

My current (pseudo) code would only add up values in the rectangular boundaries (yellow). What I need is the sum of the values within the grey boundary.

Thanks for any help!

```
    int n = 5;
    int[] array[width*height];
    int[] values[n+1];
    int* p = array[0];
    int i = 0;
    int bandwith = width /(n+1);
for(int i= 0; i< n; i ++)
{ 
   for (int nRow = 0; nRow < height; ++nRow){
            for (int nColumn = 0, nOff = 0; nColumn < width; ++nColumn){

                if(nColumn < (i+1)*bandwidth && nColumn > i*bandwidth
                && nRow < (i+1)*bandwidth && nRow > i*bandwidth)
                 {
                  values[i] += p[nOff++];
                 }
            }
            p += width;
    }
    i++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If this was a 2D array - would you know how to do it? or is your problem making it circle-like, even in 2D array?

Comment: @amit I think I have problems with the circular boundary condition.

Comment: Are there elliptic quarters or perfect circle quarters?

Comment: Perfect circle quarters!

Comment: But why do you use different radii for x and y axes?

Comment: I think I will just calculate the radius `r` of a given coordinate from the polar version of the coordinate using `sqrt(y*y+x*x)` and check whether it's inbetween `n*bandwith` and `(n+1)*bandwidth`. Correct?

Comment: Trick : you don't have to use sqrt : compare `y*y+x*x` to `radius*radius`

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate integer part of expression

```
v = sqrt(y*y+x*x) / bandwidth
```

This gives you a number of ring fragment (0 for central circle quarter, 1 for the first ring segment and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Since the the distance around the circle circumference is 2*π*r, if you divide the circle into n equal parts you will have n slices with arc lenght:http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Circles.faq.question.336647.html.